# Is there a way to force $c->uri_for in Catalyst to generate a URI that begins with https?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I've written a web application using Catalyst that has a lot of forms and needs to run over https. There are no hard-coded URLs, everything uses `$c->uri_for` or `$c->req->uri`. Everything worked great in the development environment using the dev server running over http.

Today, when I went ahead and deployed the application, I noticed a problem. The way our production environment is currently setup, client browsers talk to a F5 load-balancer over HTTPS and the F5 talks to the web server on the internal network over HTTP.

> [ Browser ] ---HTTPS---> [ F5 ] ---HTTP---> [ Web Server ]

Now, because the web server only gets `HTTP` requests, all URIs are generated starting with HTTP. This means:

```
<form action='[% c.uri_for('/secure/form') %]' method='post'>
```

becomes:

```
<form action='http://websitename.org/secure/form' method='post'>
```

and now all browsers complain you are submitting data over an insecure connection. I need that `c.uri_for` to begin with https.

The app needed to go live today, so I did a mass search/replace for all form actions to this:

```
<form action='[% c.uri_for('/secure/form') | replace('http:', 'https:'%]' method='post'>
```

Well, now that breaks development, so I conditionalized the form actions based on a config key:

```
[% IF c.config.production %]
  <form action='[% c.uri_for('/secure/form') | replace ('http:', 'https:') %]' method='post'>
[% ELSE %]
  <form action='[% c.uri_for('/secure/form') %]' method='post'>
[% END %]
```

Needless to say, this all just seems wrong on multiple levels. Anyone have a better idea? And is there a way to force `$c->uri_for` to generate a URI that begins with https?

### Solution

If you're using Catalyst 5.80008 or later, set `MyApp->config(using_frontend_proxy => 1);` and simply have your proxy set the `X-Forwarded-Port` header. For Catalyst versions prior to 5.80008, still set `using_frontend_proxy` so you get the actual client_ip, but to generate the correct URIs have your web server set the environment variable `HTTPS` to `ON`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might try this configuration option:

```
MyApp->config(using_frontend_proxy => 1);
```

It's described in [Catalyst's documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/Catalyst-Runtime/lib/Catalyst.pm#PROXY_SUPPORT)

Comment: ah, yes, documentation ... I guess I should have read all of it first. Well, I just dumped the headers and while the F5 is setting 'X-forwarded-for' it is not setting 'X-Forwarded-Host' or 'X-Forwarded-Port'. I'll have those configured, set the config option and let everyone know how it does. thanks!

Comment: Ok, tested. You're correct in that I needed to set `using_frontend_proxy` in my config. However, checking the `X-Forwarded-Port` header was only added in Catalyst 5.8.0008 and I'm using 5.71. However, you did point me in the correct direction, and after looking at the code for `Catalyst::Engine::CGI` I figured all I had to do was add `SetEnv HTTPS on` in my virtual host configuration. Everything works now!

Answer (score 6):

The following works (tested):

In MyApp.pm, add the following sub:

```
sub secure_uri_for {
    my ($self, @args) = @_;
    my $u = $self->uri_for(@args);
    $u->scheme('https');
    return $u;
}
```

Now any time you want a guaranteed https, you can call `$c->secure_uri_for('whatever')`

Comment: this may not actually answer your question though.  Do you have `using_front_end_proxy 1` in your application's config?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Catalyst, but the docs for `uri_for` point to [the request object's `base` method](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Runtime/lib/Catalyst/Request.pm#%24req-%3Ebase).

I read the source, and found that `base` is a read/write method.  So, you should be able to squeeze `$req->base('https://foo.bar.com/')` into your code somewhere to get your https uris.

**Update:**

*singingfish* says that the above advice is incorrect--which wouldn't surprise me at all, it was based on a quick look at TFM.  S/He also says that the `scheme` method should be set instead.  I assume s/he is referring the the **uri** object's `scheme` method.

Further searching turned up [HTTPS Tricks on the Catalyst Wiki](http://dev.catalystframework.org/wiki/resources/httpstricks).  It shows an example of setting the scheme on the **uri** objects returned by the `uri_for_action` method.  It looks like you would need to set the scheme on every uri you request, all over your code.  So, I can't help but feel that the scheme method may not be the best choice.

I also found [this thread on the mailing list](http://lists.scsys.co.uk/pipermail/catalyst/2005-September/001689.html).   Setting `base` or setting an environment variable are both recommended methods.

This gives you several avenues of investigation.  Good luck.

Comment: This is wrong.  The correct accessor to modify is the `->scheme` method.